# spring-data delete of non-existent entity produces "Transaction marked as rollback"

Tags: jpa, transactions, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

A question that seems to have been asked many times - but maybe not so simply and none of the current answers seem to work for me.

I have a very simple web based spring-boot application with a REST controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void delete(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    boolean success = customerService.delete(id);
    if (!success) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

and I have a service with a delete method that is marked as Transactional:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public boolean delete(String id) {
    try {
        customerRepository.delete(id);
    } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I am catching the exception as I don't want my service implementation to throw exceptions on a delete if the delete is for an entity that does not exist. The customerRepository id derived from JpaRepository so is autogenerated for me.

If I try and delete an existing entity - all is fine. If I try and delete a non-existing entity then the EmptyResultDataAccessException is thrown and caught, the value false returned and then when the method ends and the transaction committed I get `javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly`.

I understand (or thought I did) what is happening I am just not sure how to go about stopping it. I have tried adding various combinations of noRollbackFor to my Transaction annotation but to no avail.

Comment: Do you need transaction in that method? Delete method has transaction already. Another workaround (which I think is better in that case) is checking if entity exists and then delete it by using `delete(entity)` method.

Comment: Which versions of Spring and Spring Data JPA are you using? I don't get any errors with the latest release versions. A [sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/42761628) is available on Github on test.

Comment: @manish spring 4.3.6 and spring-data-jpa 1.11.0 via spring-boot 1.5.1-RELEASE

Comment: @ByeBye I did originally load and check before deleting (it's what the repository impl does) but it felt wrong - I was worried the exception could still be thrown even after the initial check - but given the unit of work is tied to the thread and transaction it probably can't so is probably the best way. Removing the transaction boundary from the service and relying on the one on the repo also works nicely.